# Unrolling / expanding a dictionary of iterables into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dictionary holding lists like the following:

```
 {
 u'0HmZNYSfb2': [u'1TkTcV', u'1T8eDK', u'1T2fP4'],
 u'0HYrcjO26wS': [],
 u'0HsGjvej6U': [u'1TzoWb', u'1TbQQl'],
 u'0HsYF0oEuQ': [u'1Tgcdf'],
 u'0Ht2wIpTTc': [],
 }
```

I would like to create a dataframe that "expands" the dictionary as follows:

```
0HmZNYSfb2  1TkTcV
0HmZNYSfb2  1T8eDK
0HmZNYSfb2  1T2fP4
0HYrcjO26wS NaN
0HsGjvej6U  1TzoWb
0HsGjvej6U  1TbQQl
0HsYF0oEuQ  1Tgcdf
0Ht2wIpTTc  NaN
```

I tried with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")` but don't get the result I want (Pandas creates what's effectively a Matrix)

Also,  `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="columns")` returns:

```
"ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from your point:

```
D = {u'0HmZNYSfb2': [u'1TkTcV', u'1T8eDK', u'1T2fP4'],
     u'0HYrcjO26wS': [],
     u'0HsGjvej6U': [u'1TzoWb', u'1TbQQl'],
     u'0HsYF0oEuQ': [u'1Tgcdf'],
     u'0Ht2wIpTTc': [] }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(D, orient="index")
```

Which yields the following `df` for me:

```
                  0       1       2
0HYrcjO26wS    None    None    None
0HmZNYSfb2   1TkTcV  1T8eDK  1T2fP4
0HsYF0oEuQ   1Tgcdf    None    None
0HsGjvej6U   1TzoWb  1TbQQl    None
0Ht2wIpTTc     None    None    None
```

I would do the following:

```
df[0].fillna(np.Inf, inplace=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df[col] for col in df], axis=0)
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
df2[df2 == np.Inf] = np.NaN
```

The first command fills the `None` values with `np.Inf` to save them from being dropped in the following `dropna` on line 3. Then `pd.concat` is used to stack the columns together on top of each other. After dropping the spurious `None` values from columns 2 and 3, the `np.Inf` placeholder values can be assigned their desired value.

**Result**

```
0HmZNYSfb2     1T2fP4
0HmZNYSfb2     1T8eDK
0HsGjvej6U     1TbQQl
0HsYF0oEuQ     1Tgcdf
0HmZNYSfb2     1TkTcV
0HsGjvej6U     1TzoWb
0HYrcjO26wS       NaN
0Ht2wIpTTc        NaN
```

Comment: On this note, does Pandas treat `NaN` and `None` differently? Is the answer: it depends?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to be able to do the concat even without the list comprehension, but I could not find a way.

Comment: See Pandas docs: [values considered missing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing), excerpt: *While NaN is the default missing value marker for reasons of computational speed and convenience, we need to be able to easily detect this value with data of different types: floating point, integer, boolean, and general object. In many cases, however, the Python None will arise and we wish to also consider that “missing” or “null”.*

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you want NaN for empty lists, how about `concat()` them:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
 u'0HmZNYSfb2': [u'1TkTcV', u'1T8eDK', u'1T2fP4'],
 u'0HYrcjO26wS': [],
 u'0HsGjvej6U': [u'1TzoWb', u'1TbQQl'],
 u'0HsYF0oEuQ': [u'1Tgcdf'],
 u'0Ht2wIpTTc': [],
}
series = [pd.Series(items) if items else pd.Series([None]) for items in d.itervalues()]
pd.concat(series, keys=d.keys())
```

Comment: Thanks. Assuming that `None` is ok for empty lists. How else could this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Another one using `loc` and loops:

```
df= DataFrame(columns=[1,2])
for k in D:
    for v in D[k]:
        df.loc[row.shape[0]] = [k,v]
    if not D[k]:
        df.loc[row.shape[0]] = [k,'NaN']
```

Gives

```
             1       2
0  0HYrcjO26wS     NaN
1   0HmZNYSfb2  1TkTcV
2   0HmZNYSfb2  1T8eDK
3   0HmZNYSfb2  1T2fP4
4   0HsYF0oEuQ  1Tgcdf
5   0HsGjvej6U  1TzoWb
6   0HsGjvej6U  1TbQQl
7   0Ht2wIpTTc     NaN
```

EDIT:

This seems slower though.

```
timeit -n 1000 HYRYs()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop

timeit -n 1000 ojdos()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop

timeit -n 1000 panditas()
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.98 ms per loop
```